# LINQ to Entities materialization error

Tags: sql, linq, entity-framework, system.data.sqlite

I have Entity Framework 4 model over SQLite databese. Part of the model looks like this
[image]

All Id fields have type Guid (uniqueidentifier in SQLite table DDL). But when I run following LINQ query I get exception.

```
var query = AbonentPfrs.Select(a => 
    new 
    {
        AbPfr = a,
        Pfr = a.PfrCertificates.Select(c => c.Id), 
        Ac = a.AcCertificates.Select(c => c.Id)
    }
);
query.ToList();
```

When I run it I get

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The type of the key field 'Id' is expected to be 'System.Guid', but the value provided is actually of type 'System.String'.
```

**UPDATE:** I found out that EF generate SQL query that really returns strings as identifiers for one of the entities.

The SQL that goes to the DB `((query as ObjectQuery).ToTraceString())` looks like this:

```
SELECT 
[UnionAll1].[C2] AS [C1], 
[UnionAll1].[C3] AS [C2], 
[UnionAll1].[Id] AS [C3], 
[UnionAll1].[PfrRegNumber] AS [C4], 
[UnionAll1].[PfrUnitId] AS [C5], 
[UnionAll1].[Account_Id] AS [C6], 
[UnionAll1].[ActiveCertificate_Id] AS [C7], 
[UnionAll1].[C1] AS [C8], 
[UnionAll1].[Id1] AS [C9], 
[UnionAll1].[C4] AS [C10]
FROM  (SELECT 
  CASE WHEN ([Extent2].[Id] IS NULL) THEN NULL ELSE 1 END AS [C1], 
  1 AS [C2], 
  1 AS [C3], 
  [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
  [Extent1].[PfrRegNumber] AS [PfrRegNumber], 
  [Extent1].[PfrUnitId] AS [PfrUnitId], 
  [Extent1].[Account_Id] AS [Account_Id], 
  [Extent1].[ActiveCertificate_Id] AS [ActiveCertificate_Id], 
  [Extent2].[Id] AS [Id1], 
  NULL AS [C4]
  FROM  [AbonentPfrs] AS [Extent1]
  LEFT OUTER JOIN [Certificates] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[Id] = [Extent2].[AbonentPfr_PfrCertificates_Certificate_Id]
UNION ALL
  SELECT 
  2 AS [C1], 
  2 AS [C2], 
  2 AS [C3], 
  [Extent3].[Id] AS [Id], 
  [Extent3].[PfrRegNumber] AS [PfrRegNumber], 
  [Extent3].[PfrUnitId] AS [PfrUnitId], 
  [Extent3].[Account_Id] AS [Account_Id], 
  [Extent3].[ActiveCertificate_Id] AS [ActiveCertificate_Id], 
  NULL AS [C4], 
  [Extent4].[Id] AS [Id1]
  FROM  [AbonentPfrs] AS [Extent3]
  INNER JOIN [Certificates] AS [Extent4] ON [Extent3].[Id] = [Extent4].[AbonentPfr_AcCertificates_Certificate_Id]) AS [UnionAll1]
ORDER BY [UnionAll1].[Id] ASC, [UnionAll1].[C1] ASC
```

[image]

The last to columns are ids for Certificate entities. But the last have type Guid and the previous - string. If I run parts of the query separately then I get next column types (fot last two):

1. First select: Guid, Object
2. Second select: Object, Guid
3. Union all: Guid, Object
4. Outer select: String, Guid

Why outer select returns strings in last but one column?

Comment: I think it's because two relationships on the the same table - from AbonentPfr to Certificates. But I'm not sure...

Comment: Probably because SQLite stores GUIDs as strings? AFAIK SQLite does not have a native GUID data type.

Comment: but in all other queries it works corretly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the ordering is the point. Without ordering the result types of last two columns are Guid and Objects. With ordering - String and Guid. Both order expressions depend on `[Extent2].[Id]` column. SQLite doesn't operate Guid type so, I think, values are converted into String.
It's one of difficulties of EF4 and System.Data.SQLite integration. So I need to find a way to force EF do not generate ordering clause...

Answer (score 0):

When executing the outer join, the line `CASE WHEN ([Extent2].[Id] IS NULL) THEN NULL ELSE 1 END AS [C1]` will return a null value for `C1` when your query encounters a missing value. 
In .NET, GUID is a value type (128-bit integer), so it cannot be set to null without jumping through hoops. (see [Why isn't there a Guid.IsNullOrEmpty() method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9837602/why-isnt-there-a-guid-isnullorempty-method) for more info on the nullabilty of the GUID structure.)

Since the value returned is nullable and formatted as a xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx, it is assumed to be a string.

Comment: I've changed the picture of the result to show what type columns have. As you can see the problem is in "C9" column that is the union of `[Extent2].[Id]` and `NULL`. But the "C10" column is good - result type is Guid. And I don't see the difference. C10 is the result of union of `NULL` and `[Extent4].[Id]`. Need to say that both `[Extent2].[Id]` and `[Extent4].[Id]` have the same db type.