# Check if Nullable Guid is empty in c#

Tags: c#, nullable, guid

Quoting from an answer from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9837602/why-isnt-there-a-guid-isnullorempty-method) question.

> Guid is a value type, so a variable of type Guid can't be null to
>   start with.

What then if I see this?

```
public Nullable<System.Guid> SomeProperty { get; set; }
```

how should I check if this is null? Like this?

```
(SomeProperty == null)
```

or like this?

```
(SomeProperty == Guid.Empty)
```

Comment: There's an answer to that question that addresses a nullable guid - a.k.a. `Nullable<Guid>` or `Guid?`

Comment: I think this link would be helpful for you  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/676078/which-is-preferred-nullable-hasvalue-or-nullable-null

Comment: helpful indeed, thanks!

Comment: **NOTE** - this question is specifc. about Nullabe Guid's... For how to check if a regular `Guid` is empty: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9837602/why-isnt-there-a-guid-isnullorempty-method

Answer (score 145, accepted):

If you want be sure you need to check both

```
SomeProperty == null || SomeProperty == Guid.Empty
```

Because it can be null 'Nullable' and it can be an empty GUID something like this {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}

Comment: to confirm: Guid.Empty.ToString() == "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"

Comment: Guid is never null, but it can be Guid.Empty

Comment: Guid itself not but if you read the question it's a Nullable Guid and the hole point of Nullable is that it can be null ^^

Comment: This is the correct answer; Note that if you're serializing a `Guid` from input, if you use the *non*-nullable variant, `null` will serialize as `Guid.Empty`, which can save you a `null` check here.

Answer (score 28):

<strike>[SomeProperty.HasValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sksw8094.aspx) I think it's what you're looking for.</strike>

See DevDave's or Sir l33tname's answer instead.

EDIT : btw, you can write `System.Guid?` instead of `Nullable<System.Guid>` ;)

Comment: this is only the correct answer when using a Nullable Guid. I guess most people use `Guid?` instead of `Guid`

Comment: Not sufficient.  A null Guid is not the same as an empty Guid (i.e. Guid.Empty).  So you not only need to check Guid?.HasValue, you also have to check whether Guid?.Value == Guid.Empty.

Comment: As @Triynko has said this answer needs to be updated to also check for Guid.Empty

Comment: This incorrectly answers the question.

Answer (score 20):

Note that `HasValue` will return true for an empty `Guid`.

`bool validGuid = SomeProperty.HasValue && SomeProperty != Guid.Empty;`

Answer (score 4):

Check `Nullable<T>.HasValue`

```
if(!SomeProperty.HasValue ||SomeProperty.Value == Guid.Empty)
{
 //not valid GUID
}
else
{
 //Valid GUID
}
```

Comment: As other people have pointed out : This will indeed tell you if the Guid is null, but beware! It will return true if the Guid has value Guid.Empty.

Answer (score 3):

You should use the `HasValue` property:

`SomeProperty.HasValue`

For example:

```
if (SomeProperty.HasValue)
{
    // Do Something
}
else
{
    // Do Something Else
}
```

FYI

```
public Nullable<System.Guid> SomeProperty { get; set; }
```

is equivalent to:

```
public System.Guid? SomeProperty { get; set; }
```

The MSDN Reference:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sksw8094.aspx

Comment: As other people have pointed out : This will indeed tell you if the Guid is null, but beware! It will return true if the Guid has value Guid.Empty.

Answer (score 3):

Beginning with C# 7.1, you can use default literal to produce the default value of a type when the compiler can infer the expression type.

```
Console.Writeline(default(Guid));  
   // ouptut: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000

Console.WriteLine(default(int));  // output: 0

Console.WriteLine(default(object) is null);  // output: True
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/default

Answer (score 3):

You can create a extension method to validate the GUID.

```
public static class Validate
{
    public static void HasValue(this Guid identity)
    {
        if (identity ==  null || identity == Guid.Empty)
            throw new Exception("The GUID needs a value");
    }
}
```

And use the exension

```
    public static void Test()
    {
        var newguid = Guid.NewGuid();

        newguid.HasValue();
    }
```

Comment: I wouldn't go this route. Your method name is a true/false question and therefor it should return a boolean. I doubt there are many codebases where you'd want to throw an exception when checking for a value, especially when a nullable type is perfectly valid to pass in

Comment: OK with the general idea of this approach with two strong objections: Like jhammond has said, don't name it "hasSomething" if it's not meant to return a boolean but instead only meant to raise an Exception. Name it "AssertSomething", C++-style. More genrally, don't give a function the same name as a native function of the System. C# already defines its own HasValue for nullable types!